# What does "colonia" and "interior/dpto" means in Mexico on address lines?

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico, méxico

I'm software developer and I'm having to add these two fields that doesn't have here in my country.

What does "colonia" and "interior" means in an address line in Mexico? And "No exterior" and "no interior"?

There are two images for better context

---

Yo soy programador y tengo que adicionar estos dos campos que no existen aquí en mi país.

¿Qué significan "colonia" e "interior" en una dirección en Mexico?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Colonia is the name of the neighborhood. Interior is the number of the house/apartment.  **No** is short for "Número" (number)

Comment: I'm from Spain not from Mexico but No.Exterior and No.Interior mean "Número Exterior" and "Número Interior". Let's say that you live in New York, in 22 Main Street in a building, and your flat is in the 7th floor, door A; then your "Número exterior" is 22 and your "Número interior" is 7ºA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- According to the *Diccionario de americanismos*, a *[colonia](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=colonia)* is a neighborhood, so in that field you're just supposed to type in the name of the neighborhood you live in.
- *No.* is the abbreviation for *número*, so *no. exterior* means *exterior number*, this is the number of the building. And *no. interior* is the *interior number*, the number of the apartment inside the building.
- *Depto.* is the abbreviation of *[departamento](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CEajDW3)*, used here with the meaning of *flat* or *apartment*. Once more you're supposed to type in here the number of your apartment inside the building (the *interior number*).

Here you have an example of a Mexican address [taken from the Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_postal#M%C3%A9xico):

> C. Francisco I. Madero No. 115 Int. 1
>   Col. Nuevo Casas Grandes Centro
>   31700 Nuevo Casas Grandes, Chih.

So you have "calle Francisco I. Madero", with an exterior number of 115 and interior number of 1, in the neighborhood (*colonia*) of "Nuevo Casas Grandes Centro", postal code 31700, in the city of "Nuevo Casas Grandes", state of [Chihuahua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_(state)).